# Bounding Solve results to named variables

Tags: equation-solving, variable

> How can i bound results of my Solve function to variables properly? This metod works but causes unexpected troubles i struggle to resolve

```
q1 = {tk - T/2, w};
q2 = {tk, ak};
q3 = {tk + T/2, w};
Solve[p == 0, t]; Solve[a1*q1[[1]]^2 + a2*q1[[1]] + a3 == q1[[2]] &&
a1*q2[[1]]^2 + a2*q2[[1]] + a3 == q2[[2]] &&
a1*q3[[1]]^2 + a2*q3[[1]] + a3 == q3[[2]], {a1, a2, a3}]; 
% /. Rule -> Set;
```

Comment: First off, it's best not to use `%` unless you're doing fast prototyping. It's apt to give you headaches. Second, you can just use `{a1, a2, a3} = {a1, a2, a3} /. soln` but I'd keep it as rules, myself.

Comment: Check this carefully to see it works. `{{a1,a2,a3}}=ReplaceAll[{a1,a2,a3}, Solve[a1*q1[[1]]^2 + a2*q1[[1]] + a3 == q1[[2]] &&
a1*q2[[1]]^2 + a2*q2[[1]] + a3 == q2[[2]] && a1*q3[[1]]^2 + a2*q3[[1]] + a3 == q3[[2]], {a1,a2,a3}]]` and then look at the value assigned to a1 or the value assigned to a2... As you have seen, you can use `/.` as an abbreviation for `ReplaceAll`. Look carefully at how many layers of `{{}}` there are in the result returned from `Solve` and make  certain those match the number in any assignment.